# Slide show not running well when using pjax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, pjax

I use [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) to call a page with ajax. But when a page that uses a slide show called, why my slide show was not running well? It seems that the page **can't run jquery or slide show javascript**. Because if I call the page (refresh) normally (without pjax) slide show running smoothly.

My pjax code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#content');
    });
</script>
```

My controller code (Using [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/)) :

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        $this->renderPartial('index',array(
            'dataArtikel'=>$dataArtikel,
        ));
    }else{
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataArtikel'=>$dataArtikel,
        ));
    }
}
```

How do I fix my pjax code? Is there an API to reload the page with jquery to call pjax? Or I need to change my code in controller?

Thanks before...

Answer (score 0):

If the pjax link is in the page that is loaded by pjax, you will need to 'pjaxify' that link on load. Put this somewhere in the original page (maybe the header or footer):

```
        $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
            $('a[data-pjax]').pjax();
        });
```